# Setting cache-control on all folders' assets except one

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I need to apply the following location rule for every single folder of my app with the exception of /forum and its children:

```
location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif)$ {
  expires 1M;
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

I tried out setting it to `location ~* ^/forum/.*\.(?:jpg|jpeg)$` but it doesn't look like it's working the way I want it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solver I came up with:

```
location /forum {
...
}

location / {
   location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif)$ {
...
   }
...
}
```

Simply separate the location directives and adjust commands accordingly.